# Calling DeviceIoControl async in kernel

Tags: c, asynchronous, kernel, driver, minifilter

We have OverLapped structure in user mode. For instance we can call [DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) with overlapped member to get event raised when this call will be complited. But what kernel mode? How can I send async DeviceIoControl in kernel with callback?  (FsRtlIssueDeviceIoControl is sync)

Comment: [FsRtlIssueDeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh971596.aspx): *"The FsRtlIssueDeviceIoControl routine sends a **synchronous** device I/O control request to a target device object."* It's completed, when it returns. As is the case with all synchronous calls. Maybe I just didn't get the question.

Comment: I corrected the wuestion.. I can't find any async DeviceIoControl in kernel

Comment: Google "windows drivers asynchronous device io request" and take the first hit.

Comment: @HansPassant as you can see first hit is only about Wdf driver and am ascing about minifiler context (see tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use IoCallDriver() to send your IOCTL with an completion routine set using IoSetCompletionRoutine(). but still completion can synch or asynch it depends on the target driver completing the IOCTL.